# Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint (vs code)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0

Steps to replicate error:

```
dotnet new webapi -o TodoApi
cd TodoApi
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
code -r ../TodoApi
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
Press yes on the pop-up
Press control+F5
Select .NET 5+ and .NET core
This auto generates launch.json and tasks.json
```

### Now I press control+F5 to run the project and it gives below output:

```
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Using launch settings from 'C:\Users\Archpo\Downloads\TodoApi\Properties\launchSettings.json' [Profile 'TodoApi']...
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run(String url)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\Archo\Downloads\TodoApi\Program.cs:line 25
```

I again run `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`. Then press Control+F5 - same error as above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `certmgr.msc`

Expand `Personal\Certificates`

Delete those certificates where `Friendly Name` column value is `ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate`

Close the window

Run `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Go to visual studio code and press control+F5

No error reported.

Answer (score 0):

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date. To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.

If you are writing with dot Net Core program, go to launchsettings.json file and remove https://localhost:7255 in "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7255;http://localhost:5248"

Comment: or  run the project with iis Express